# Create XML element without closing tag using XSLT

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, xml, xslt

I need to be able to create XML elements in the following format using XSLT:

```
<element foo="x" bar="y" />
```

I seem to be limited to:

```
<element foo="x" bar="y"></element>
```

The reason is we have a process change but the interface to the client cannot change. You may suggest that these are essentially equal and you would be right but we cant, however, assume our clients are using sensible XML parsing techniques.

I have tried:

```
<Mapping>
   <xsl:attribute name="Source">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Source"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="Destination">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Destination"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</Mapping>
```

which obviously adds the unwanted end tag, and:

```
<xsl:element name="Mapping">
   <xsl:attribute name="Source">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Source"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="Destination">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Destination"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:element>
```

this still added the unwanted end tag.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The two are semantically identical. If your clients see that as a change then surely that's their problem not yours?

Comment: Can you show us the .NET code doing the transformation? There is no XSLT way to enforce a certain format for serializing empty elements as e.g. `<foo/>` or `<foo /` but as far as I am aware .NET's XmlWriter implementations by default output `<foo />` and not `<foo></foo>` so I am astonished that you say you get the long form with an end tag.

Comment: Googling gave http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/xmlandnetfx/thread/3f5a3a5f-d088-4664-9216-e4ff8e577a0f. Have you tried it?

Comment: As far as the clients seeing these as different, that is our problem. There are multiple PAYING clients that have their own implementations some not technically the best way of doing it but it works for them. This is business at the end of the day and money talks before any opinion on the correct way to parse XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone help?

**In .NET there** *is* **a way to achieve this**:

Write your own class derived from **[`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx)** and overwrite all necessary overloads of the **[`WriteElementString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aex0e7zs.aspx)** method, so that you are in full control of the serialization of elements.

Finally, use [**`XslCompiledTransform.Transform()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163430.aspx) passing as argument an instance of your class.

Comment: There is quite a bit more legwork in doing it this way but much less painful than having the first line support team throwing staplers and rotten eggs at me

Comment: @jaywayco: we are using an XhtmlWriter derived from XmlWriter. Yes, quite a lot of methods are overriden, but the overrides in most cases are just a few lines long. And once you have this class, you can use it with any transformation.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to force XSLT to use the short-hand form. Even if there was such a way, it'd probably be implementation-specific. As a matter of fact, if I try something like your examples in XMLSpy, it actually uses the short notation for the output, regardless of how I set `xml:space`.

You might want to check what settings can be made on the XSLT processor being used and if it supports something relevant.

To be honest, I'd say that if any client cannot establish the equivalence of `<element/>` and `<element></element>`, it's not XML-compliant to the point of being broken. It's their problem and they should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing all white-spaces after `<Mapping>` (or `<xsl:element name="Mapping">`) and the follow-up elements? The XSLT engine might consider them as content and thus opens a regular element only to find out that there isn't anything to write.

```
<xsl:element name="Mapping"><xsl:attribute name="Source"><xsl:value-of select="@Source" /></xsl:attribute></xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem at all as Joe comments. You should be able however, to load and normalize the generated XML:

```
$str = <<<XML
<root>
    <element foo="x" bar="y"></element>
</root>
XML;

$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadXML($str);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <element foo="x" bar="y"/>
</root>
```

As loading and saving can be triggered by the [`normalizeDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.normalizedocument.php) function, in your code you might be able to just add it after you've done the transformation.

Comment: Which variant did you try? Are you using the PHP or .NET XSLT processor?

Answer (score 0):

It really shouldn't matter which way empty XML elements are serialized, since any XML parser will treat them as equivalent. But if you want it done differently, you could choose a different XSLT processor. Saxon is available on .NET and if you switch, you'll get all the benefits of XSLT 2.0 as well as solving this little problem.